# wordpress site not working after updating to version 5

Tags: php, wordpress

Getting the error message after updating the wordpress to 5.0.  Website is down and below error is coming in the error.log file.  How can I resolve this issue and get my website up and running again.

I am getting 500 error.

```
PHP message: PHP Warning:  call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'wp_check_term_meta_support_prefilter' not found or invalid function name in /var/www/html/ampletrails.com/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 288
PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method WP_Scripts::set_translations() in /var/www/html/ampletrails.com/public_html/wp-includes/script-loader.php:490\nStack trace:
  #0 /var/www/html/ampletrails.com/public_html/wp-includes/script-loader.php(740): wp_default_packages_scripts(Object(WP_Scripts))
  #1 /var/www/html/ampletrails.com/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(286): wp_default_packages(Object(WP_Scripts))
  #2 /var/www/html/ampletrails.com/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array)
  #3 /var/www/html/ampletrails.com/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(515): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
  #4 /var/www/html/ampletrails.com/public_html/wp-includes/class.wp-scripts.php(148): do_action_ref_array('wp_default_scri...', Array)
  #5 /var/www/html/ampletrails.com/public_html/wp-includes/class.wp-scripts.php(131): WP_Scripts->init()
  #6 /var/www/html/ampletrails.com/public_html/wp-includes/functions.wp-scripts.php(23): WP_Scripts->__construct()
  #7 /var/w...'
```

Comment: Were your plugins updated prior to the WP update? Do you have backups of your files and database?

Comment: You need to Update PHP version of your web hosting as required by the Wordpress 5.0 otherwise some of the core functions will not work and you will get these types of errors.

Comment: Agree with @tshimkus. It is required to take your existing website backup before update to the WordPress 5.0

Comment: @tshimkus yes I have the backup and all the plugins are updated.

Comment: PHP version is updated to the most recent stable one.